# How to manipulate and store precise numbers in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to store numbers with variable number of decimal points? there can be anywhere from 1 to 100 decimal points I guess. What's the thing with float datatype? Why do they call it approximate number? Decimal is good, but it is a fixed precision datatype as far as I understand. Is there any good articles on precise numbers? My database is going to interact with .net front-end and I also need to display these precisions on the front-end.

Comment: 100 digits after the decimal? I don't think you need that much precision to land a probe on Mars.

Comment: Please be more exact in what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: It is estimated there are 10^80 atoms in the observable universe.  You want to store a number that is 1/10^100.  You may be a little unrealistic on your precision requirement.

Answer (score 3):

From wiki:

> The term floating point refers to the fact that the radix point
>   (decimal point, or, more commonly in computers, binary point) can
>   "float"; that is, it can be placed anywhere relative to the
>   significant digits of the number. This position is indicated
>   separately in the internal representation, and floating-point
>   representation can thus be thought of as a computer realization of
>   scientific notation. Over the years, several different floating-point
>   representations have been used in computers; however, for the last ten
>   years the most commonly encountered representation is that defined by
>   the IEEE 754 Standard.
>
> The advantage of floating-point representation over fixed-point (and
>   integer) representation is that it can support a much wider range of
>   values. For example, a fixed-point representation that has seven
>   decimal digits with two decimal places, can represent the numbers
>   12345.67, 123.45, 1.23 and so on, whereas a floating-point
>   representation (such as the IEEE 754 decimal32 format) with seven
>   decimal digits could in addition represent 1.234567, 123456.7,
>   0.00001234567, 1234567000000000, and so on. The floating-point format
>   needs slightly more storage (to encode the position of the radix
>   point), so when stored in the same space, floating-point numbers
>   achieve their greater range at the expense of precision.

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx for fixed point data tpes.

Best you can do with a primitive data type is 38.  If you really want 100 places, you could use a varchar and implement operations in your application.